# Postfix aliases db: No such file or directory

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to use a `postfix` on a local `Ubuntu 12.04` with `ZoneMinder`.
I installed from `Ubuntu Desktop` the `Postfix` package and its dependency.

Now if I try to send email with following command it works good:

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" myemail@gmail.com
```

Then if an alarm from `ZoneMinder` sends an email I get the following

```
Apr 16 17:05:18 ubuntu postfix/local[11541]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases is unavailable. open database /etc/aliases.db: No such file or directory
```

and on if i run postqueue -q i get queued emails with (alias database unavailable)

```
A09B4A40C16      422 Thu Apr 16 16:59:37  destination@email.net
                                                  (alias database unavailable)
                                         root@nameofthehost.net
```

I tried to set `pownership` to `postfix` as suggested in other post with the following

```
sudo chown postfix:postfix -R /var/lib/postfix
```

and restarted postfix, but din't help.

The main.cf has the following

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

```
# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = ubuntu
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = meridianozero.net, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

What should I check?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is because you have

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
```

The `hash:` means, that you must have a database file containing the hashes, as described in [Postfix lookup table types](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types):

> An indexed file type based on hashing. This is available only on
>   systems with support for Berkeley DB databases. Public database files
>   are created with the postmap(1) or postalias(1) command, and private
>   databases are maintained by Postfix daemons. The database name as used
>   in "hash:table" is the database file name without the ".db" suffix.

Therefore, as described in the documentation of [alias_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#alias_maps):

> If you change the alias database, run `postalias /etc/aliases` (or
>   wherever your system stores the mail alias file), or simply run
>   `newaliases` to build the necessary DBM or DB file.

This will build the `/etc/aliases.db` file from information in `/etc/aliases`.

Naturally you must run either of these commands also during initial setup.

Comment: So shell I remove postfix and reinstall it ?

Comment: **No.** Please read my answer. It is already shorter than the manual.

Answer (score 3):

### Problem:

I received the same error when migrating Postfix to an Alpine Linux Docker container:

```
postfix/smtpd[189]: error: open database /etc/postfix/aliases.lmdb: No such file or directory
```

### Solution:

The reason why the error was puked was because the command `newaliases` hadn't been run which creates the file `/etc/postfix/aliases.lmdb`.

To clear the error I executed:

```
newaliases
postfix reload
```

This created the missing file and Postfix was now happy.